# Memory leak using BlobReader (Google App Engine, Python 2.7)

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Using Python 2.7 in Google AppEngine, in order to serve a **patched** binary file to the client, I do this:

- Read the original file from the blobstore, using BlobReader
- Output the data from the BlobReader up to the patch point
- Output the patched bytes
- Output the remainder of the original data

The system works, but there seems to be a memory leak somewhere because after every request, the memory used by the current instance increases by TWICE the size of the blob: E.g. if the blob is 8 MB, after the request the memory used by the instance increases by 16 MB. As a consequence, after just a few such requests, the instance is forcibly terminated by GAE, with an error message of "exceeded soft private memory limit".

Here is a shortened version of the code that produces the memory leak:

```
class CurrentVer(db.Expando):
    "singleton entity with reference to the blob and starting position of the patch"
    patch_start = db.IntegerProperty()
    blob = blobstore.BlobReferenceProperty()

def out_blob(handler):
    # prepare a patch string
    patch_string = "<CONFIG><A>A316</A></CONFIG>"
    # read blob key and starting position of patch
    CurrVer = CurrentVer.get_by_key_name("CurrentVer")
    patch_start  = CurrVer.patch_start
    blob_key = str(CurrVer.blob.key())
    CurrVer = None
    # open BlobReader object with 1MB buffer, as shown in GAE docs:
    blob_reader = blobstore.BlobReader(blob_key, buffer_size=1048576)       
    # read original data until patch point, and output it:
    handler.response.out.write(blob_reader.read(patch_start))           
    # output patch bytes
    handler.response.out.write(patch_string)
    # skip the bytes that have been patched
    blob_reader.seek(patch_start + len(patch_string))
    # read remaining original data until the end, and output it
    handler.response.out.write(blob_reader.read())
    blob_reader.close()
    blob_reader = None
    gc.collect()

def gc_collect(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        gc.collect()
        self.response.out.write("<html><body>Called cg.collect()</body></html>")

class patch_blob(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        out_blob(self)

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/patch_blob.*', patch_blob),
    ('/gc_collect.*', gc_collect)], 
    debug=True)
```

When the code runs (URL = /patch_blob), after every request the memory used by the instance increases by twice the size of the blob, like this:

Request 1: 55 MB

Request 2: 73 MB

Request 3: 90 MB

...and so on, until I get this error in the logs:

(c) Exceeded soft private memory limit with 140.504 MB after servicing 5 requests total

(w) After handling this request, the process that handled this request was found to be using too much memory and was terminated. This is likely to cause a new process to be used for the next request to your application. If you see this message frequently, you may have a memory leak in your application.

Can anybody explain what is happening, and how to avoid what looks like an egregious memory leak? (Luckily, GAE still serves the last request before triggering the error, but I'm sure this is an undesirable thing to happen and I'd like to avoid it...)

Thanks!!!

Comment: Whats with the `self.handler.response` what request handler are you using ?  do you have the handler wrapped in some higher level class. Have you tried calling `gc.collect()` once you are out of scope of the blob_reader.  You probably need to provide more code.

Comment: self.handler = webapp2.RequestHandler

Comment: I'll research gc.collect() and I'll report if it helps...

Comment: ick, why are you storing the handler instance as an attribute of something else ?  You should definately include more code

Comment: gc.collect() helped partially: when I use it, the memory increases by twice the amount of the blob size the first 3 times the method is called, but after that, it doesn't increase any more.

Comment: You should still show us a more complete set of code, I think you must still hold a reference to the data somewhere.

Comment: OK, I entered an entire (though scaled down) application that produces the memory leak. When I run the above code I the memory used by the instance increases by twice the size of the blob with every request.

Comment: where are you sticking your gc.collect()

Comment: Right, I call gc.collect() after closing the BlobReader object, AND I also made a separate handler that just calls gc.collect() (just to be sure gc.collect() is called as much out of scope as possible) but even with all that, the memory leaks as much as before. See edited code above for the placement of gc.collect()